# How to export annotations in iBooks for Mac?

Tags: mac, books, epub

I've been using iBooks to read `.epub`s that I've downloaded from the Internet, and made many annotations in them.

How can I export the annotations to another Mac, or share them all at once?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two options.

This app is still not yet released http://www.compendiumsapp.com/

The other technique involves an app called Digested. I took the hint from here http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/beyond-highlighting-how-to-get-the-most-from-your-annotations--cms-20013 and should work for your other Macs.

> ...sync your iBooks with your iOS device, and use the Digested app to
>   copy the annotations back to your Mac. It's a roundabout way, but it
>   does work.